# Sharepoint 2010 - Make assigning users easier

Tags: workflow, lookup-column, string

we are using Sharepoint 2010 and maintaining an Action Item/Issue tracker list (for a limited number of people, <10). To make assigning Action Items to users easier I want to implement to option to either click on checkboxes

[ ] Jan
[ ] Chris
[ ] Sara

to select to whom to assign this task or to use the Sharepoint lookup and maintain a list of users (with 2 rows, one row saying Jan and the other one containing the link to this person) tasks can be assigned to in a seperate list (better option in my opinion).

I then want to use a Workflow to map the list with names to the real "Assigned to" field shown in the Action Item entry. This is where I'm currently stuck, I tried various options but they all don't work because I cannot do String modifications.

Anyone has a solution how to implement this?

Thanks and BR
Orbit.

Answer (score 0):

You can either use SharePoint's default people picker column when you assign the tasks. Or you can make a list of all people you want to use, and then make a lookup column to choose from these people when you do the task, and make the column's type of multi selection. Is this what you were asking for?

**Updated Answer**

Since you can't do a lookup on a "People Picker" column. So what you would do is, create a list for the people you want to assign tasks to. Let the title column be the name of the person, so you would just write their names here, and created another column call it "Email". So you will have around 10 items in this list filled manually with people's names and emails.

Then in your list, make a lookup column to lookup this list, choose the Title column to be looked up, Add more columns to this lookup selections, select the Email column as well, and click OK to create your lookup.

Modify your view, and hide the Email column, so you would only have the name of the user in the view, and that's it. In your workflow you can send email to the Email field, which will be comma delimited

Comment: Hi,thanks for your answer. The people picker I do not want to use because it's very slow and involves typing, I want an easier solution.
Problem is, when I make a column with multi-selection and lookup the email addresses, I get them in the formats String:
;#email.email@company.com;#email2.email@company.com;# or as Comma Delimited: email.email@company.com,email2.email@company.com and both cannot be assigned to real people as the Directory doesn't with with # and ,. I need it semicolon delimited, is there an easy way to get that?

Comment: Please read my updated answer.